# Polynomial kernel in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, kernel-trick

So I have put together a nice logistic regression program that works quite well. Now, I have used two dimensions to test it and see how it works, and guided by some online tutorials, have increased the dimensionality using a polynomial kernel. I was wondering whether I could now increase my data dimensionality and still use a polynomial kernel, but I am unsure about how to go about writing the kernel. I guess that what I want is $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}')= (\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}' + 1)^{d}$, where $\mathbf{x} \in R^{N}$, and $N >> 2$.

I mean, one can always expand that expression, but it gets quickly umanageable after N=3 and d=4, for example!